# E commerce load test with complete flow

Tags: jmeter, e-commerce, load-testing

I'm trying to do a load test of e commerce site with complete flow from product search, login to add to cart and submit. Product search and anonymous order is working fine but when I'm trying to run script for registered user it's not working. How can I fix this?[Click here to download script](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04149992050813441832)

Comment: Hi Ajay. In general we ask that questions show the necessary code in the question itself - can you delete that file locker link and move the code into the question body? There is a formatting tool available. If the code is very long (or many files) then try to cut it/them down to the smallest case that will reproduce your problem.

Comment: In order to run the script, would a reader have to have access to your load target? If so, that will make it harder for them to reproduce the problem. You may need to add more information to your script to help your readers given that they may not be able to run this - do you have run/error logs, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Your "download" link is broken or expired or whatever.

Most probably your request doesn't work for authorised users due to missing or improperly working **correlation**. Modern web applications cannot be just recorded and replayed as they widely use dynamic request parameters mostly for [security reasons](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). So if this is the case your test needs to look as follows:

- Open Login Page (usually GET request)

  - Extract dynamic parameters using one of matching JMeter [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- Perform Login (usually POST Request) providing not only credentials, but also dynamic parameters values from the first request

Also make sure you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan - it represents browser cookies and automatically deals with cookie-based authentication

---

You might want to try an alternative way of recording a JMeter test - using cloud-based proxy which is capable of exporting recorded tests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic correlation of any dynamic parameters detected. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more information.